# Block IP addresses in Apache VHost with proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I have the vhost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName somename.com

        <Proxy *>
                order deny,allow
                Deny from 65.74.5.130
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8890/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8082/
</VirtualHost>
```

The IPs I put in the `Proxy` section are not being blocked.  Am I not understanding the correct deny/allow order?  Or is there some other directive I need to be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `order` directive is wrong.

`Order` indicates how apache evaluates `allow` and `deny` directives. In and `deny,allow` configuration, you first specify your denied origins, and then the exceptions (allowed origins) to the denied list.

As your banned IP matches both directives, you are introducing it as an exception to the deny rule, allowing it to access freely.

Use `order allow,deny` with the same `deny` and `allow` directives you have to restrict its access:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName somename.com

    <Proxy *>
            order allow,deny
            Deny from 65.74.5.130
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8890/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8082/
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Note:** the last parameter in `order` sets the **default** action **if no match** for neither `deny` nor `allow` is found, so having a `xxxx from all` is not necessary, but most people like to set it explicitly.

This is equivalent:

```
order allow,deny
Deny from 65.74.5.130
Allow from all
```

- `65.74.5.130` matches both `allow` and `deny`, applying order (1st allow, last deny), it will deny access.
- any other IP would match `allow`, so it will allow acccess.

to this:

```
order deny,allow
Deny from 65.74.5.130
```

- `65.74.5.130` matches only `deny`, so it denies access
- any other IP would not match any `allow` or `deny`, so it will take the default action `allow`, allowing access.